# Notation of the gradient

Tags: notation, vector-analysis, education

I have problems understanding a specific notation of the gradient, more specifically the following question

What is the meaning of the gradient notation grad_x H where H is a function?

My attempt at answering this question is:

Assume that H = H(x,y) then we know that grad_x ( H(x,y) ) = d/dx ( H(x,y) )

Is this correct?

Comment: No, not correct.  Look up some definitions and try again.

Comment: Context dependent.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1466839/123905 for three possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, especially Eric Towers for the link. Looking up the link by we see that grad_x H = (∂x1H,...,∂xnH), but assuming that x\in R then we have grad_x H = ∂x ( H ) which then confirms my reasoning in my question?